# DIVs positions in gallery of images

Tags: html, css, image, gallery

I'm creating a responsive skeleton of a gallery that will be inserted in a wordpress. The gallery is made of `images` of different sizes. The thing is I can't figure out how to stick `div`, which are on the "second row", right below the `div` of the "first row".

Here is a codepen of my actual work:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JdXPde

And I want my gallery to look like: http://webplantmedia.com/starter-themes/wordpresscanvas/features/gallery/gallery-columns/#gallery-6

Comment: Its not really clear what you are trying to achive

Comment: Your images in your codepen are not working. Therefore I can not see what the problem is.

Comment: Sorry for that, @Pierezzz, it works for me.
I edited my post and added an example.

Comment: can you perhaps update your codepen with images that are visible. I do not know if it due to the fact that it is forbidden for me to watch the images but now I can not really see what the problem is @suniz

Comment: is probably because you are logged into the service that is providing the image?

Comment: It seems that it is something like that @alexrogins so I updated the `img`.
Can you see it now ?

Comment: Yeh they're not all loading though. e.g. item2. Your hosting is extremely slow. Try sticking them up somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahh, it loaded eventually. I don't think you can achieve what you are after with inline, inline-block nor floats. I think you would need to use absolute positioning as per what they are using on the link you forwarded. I can recommend using isotope https://github.com/metafizzy/isotope which does all that for you. It is a great tool.

Depending on your browser support matrix you could use CSS columns if you don't wish to use JS.

```
.wrapper { 
    column-width: 500px;
    /* plus browser prefixes */
    -moz-column-width: 500px; 
    -webkit-column-width: 500px; 
}
```

Stick a div around your elements with a class of wrapper.

Comment: Ok, is there a way to make it works with the `flex` and `inline-flex` properties ? I saw an other system of `display` wich is `grid` but it's only working with IE.

I will check isotope too but if I can manage to find a solution with no js, it would be better.